# find: missing argument to -exec not copying

Tags: linux, bash, find, debian

Want copy all files from catalog /usr/sbin to other folder with range beetwen 500kb and a 4M.

First line of code, that I write it's normally do.

```
find /usr/sbin/ type -f -size +500k -size -4M
```

But when I add -exec code action above to do it's print err:

```
find /usr/sbin/ type -f -size +500k -size -4M -exec cp /usr/sbin '/dest-catalog'
find: missing argument to `-exec`
Try 'find --help' for more information
```

Can't find any answer despite study man, find --help, search answer.

Comment: try to select any answer as correct(since I could see you don't select answer as correct ones) out of any of the answers to complete the thread.

Comment: Try `man find` look at the exec part, it tells you the syntax of the command

Comment: LOL you may as well accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks RavinderSingh13 & 123. Found solution write this code:

```
find /dest_catalog/ -type f -size +500k -size -4M -exec cp -nv {} ./ \;
```